# How args.length is getting used to set the max time limit Java concurrency program

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I was learning about concurrency in the Oracle official tutoring page and I looked through a code example where there's a thread that waits 4 seconds to print an element from a String array but at the same time sets a "patience" variable(one hour) that interrupts the thread in case that the process takes more than an hour( though this would never happen because there are only 4 elements in the string array separated by lapses of 4 seconds) well my doubt is in the declaration and validation of the patience time, it's the only part that's giving me trouble. here's the code `

```
  long patience= 1000 * 60 * 60;

   if (args.length > 0)
   {
       try{
           patience= Long.parseLong(args[0]);
       }

    catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
              threadMessage("Argument must be an integer");
            }
   }`
```

Comment: Your "doubt is in the declaration and validation ...". What are you doubting? What is you *question*?

Comment: "How args.length is getting used to set the max time limit": it isn't. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> Declaration of patience :-

```
long patience= 1000 * 60 * 60;
```

Above line is declaring the default value of patience that is 1 hour.
Above value of patience is used only when command line argument is not present.

```
if (args.length > 0)
   {
       try{
           patience= Long.parseLong(args[0]);
       }
```

In above code you are saying if command line argument is present then assign it to patience.

a) Command line arguments are passed as String array i.e. args, so you are checking the length of array, if it has length greater than 1, which means some argument is passed.
b) Since, command line argument is a String value, you are converting it to long by using `parseLong(args[0])`, where your are parsing the first element of array args.
c) If passed argument cannot be parsed to a long value, you are throwing `NumberFormatException` e.g. If you pass abc, it cannot be parsed to a long value.

[Tutorial for passing command line argument to java program](http://www.javatpoint.com/command-line-argument).

Remember Thread class sleep and join method takes milliseconds as an argument so value provided by you as a command line argument need to be in milliseconds.
So better use the below code:-

```
 patience = Long.parseLong(args[0]) * 1000; //convert seconds to milliseconds
```

> Validation:-

Two ways by which you can validate the patience
1) First pass a small value of patience < 4 seconds, say 2 seconds. You could immediately see the interruption by main thread after approx 2 seconds. By this approach received the below output:

```
Output:-

    main: Starting MessageLoop thread
    main: Waiting for MessageLoop thread to finish
    main: Still waiting...
    main: Still waiting...
    main: Tired of waiting!
    Thread-0: I wasn't done!
    main: Finally!
```

2) You can put the MessageLoop thread to sleep for more than 1 hour, in case you are using the default value of patience. See the code below:-

```
Thread t = new Thread(new MessageLoop());
            Thread.sleep(patience+10000l);
            t.start();
```